# Two scaffolds into one page because of navigation in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I have an issue with the navigation process in my Flutter app.
First, I have a home page that has a button. When I press search, I go to the search page, obviously, and the results will appear on the home page again.
If no results were found, a dialog would appear that says "Try again" and has an OK button.
I want to press the OK button to navigate to the search page again. But there is a problem with the scaffolds like the image below. How can I fix this?
And my home page code, for alert dialog is like this:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
print(widget.selectedURL);
return MaterialApp(
  home: Center(
    child: FutureBuilder<List<Pet>>(
      future: API.get_pets(widget.selectedURL),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasData) {
          List<Pet>? pet_data = snapshot.data;
          print(pet_data?.length);
          return Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            child:(pet_data?.length == 0)
                    ? AlertDialog(
                        title: const Text("Failed"),
                        alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
                        content: const Text(
                            'No Pets Found. Please try different search options.'),
                        actions: [
                          TextButton(
                            child: const Text("OK"),
                            onPressed: () => Navigator.pushReplacement(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const Search())),
                          )
                        ],
                      )
                    : ListView.builder(
//showing the list of results    

)
```

[image]

Comment: try removing `MaterialApp` from this snippet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you are wrapping everything inside a `MaterialApp`.

`MaterialApp` defines a Navigator property, which means it should be at the top-level of your application and it should be unique. If you have two different `MaterialApp` they will use their own Navigator, hence they will not share routes. See more informations here [MaterialApp](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/MaterialApp-class.html).

The usual design is:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
          body: YourWidgets(
                [...]
                )//YourWidgets
             )//Scaffold
          );//MaterialApp
}
```

Try removing `MaterialApp`, or changing your `MaterialApp` to something else, like `Material` if you really need additional customization.